# R, Standard error (IRT) Plotting an inverse function

Tags: r

I was following a tutorial on creating information functions, I completed the tutorial by now am looking to take it one more step and have been stalemated. The tutorial I was following is below.

http://www.gonulates.com/psychometrics/fishers-information-function-for-the-four-parameter-model-4pm/

```
irt.4PM.Info <- function(theta,item.par,D=1.7) {
# This function calculates the Fisher information for
# Four Parameter Model, given item parameters and ability.
#
# item.par should be a matrix with four columns:
# Each row represents an item,
# first column represents a parameters (item discrimination)
# second column represents b parameters (item difficulty)
# third column represents c parameters(pseudo-guessing parameter)
# fourth column represents d parameters (upper asymptote)
# theta can be a single number or a vector.

return(t(sapply(theta,
   FUN = function (x) (
     (D * item.par[,1])^2 * (item.par[,4] - item.par[,3])^2)/
     ((item.par[,3] + item.par[,4] *
       exp(D*item.par[,1] * (x - item.par[,2]))) *
     (1 - item.par[,3] + (1-item.par[,4]) *
       exp(D*item.par[,1] * (x-item.par[,2]))) *
     (1 + exp(-D * item.par[,1] * (x - item.par[,2])))^2) )))
}
theta.2 <- c(-1,-.5,0,1,2)
itpars <- data.frame(a = c(1,  1,.75),
                 b = c(0,-.5,  1),
                 c = c(0,  0, .2),
                 d = c(1,  1,.98));
itpars

##      a    b   c    d
## 1 1.00  0.0 0.0 1.00
## 2 1.00 -0.5 0.0 1.00
## 3 0.75  1.0 0.2 0.98
theta.3 <- seq(-4,4,by=0.01)
item.1.pars <- data.frame(a=1.2,b=-0.6,c=.1,d=1)
plot(theta.3,irt.4PM.Info(theta.3,item.1.pars),type="l",
 main="Information Functon",
 xlab="Theta", ylab="Information")
```

What I am looking to do is plot the inverse of function I have right now.  That is, the function looks like a bell curve and I would like to have the inverse of this function (upside down bell curve)

The curve I am looking to make is the standard error which is the reciprocal of information SE = 1/I^.5 (I=information)

Comment: What do you mean by inverse? Your example doesn't run.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik The source code of the function `irt.4PM.Info()` (as well as the code posted above) is in the link given in the OP. If you copy-paste that function the code runs.

Comment: @RHertel and now imagine the site under the link goes offline or the link changes. And we have a dead post that helps only OP at best. It's general SO policy to include all the resources in the post, if possible.

Comment: I'm not saying it's good practice, just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik l updated all the code, if you copy/paste to R it should work.  As I clarified in the main post I am looking for a way to take the inverse of the final plot (to make an upside down bell).

Comment: did you inspect, what is produced by `theta.3,irt.4PM.Info`? I don't understand why you don't just compute the SE from the output. But maybe this is due to all those nested calls (which IMO is bad practice). EDIT: also, I don't think this is a programming rather than a statistical topic which is better suited here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/